# Ошибка npm code ENOENT no such file or directory

Tags: reactjs, npm

Ошибка при наборе команды npm start. Устанавливала reactjs

```
npm ERR! path /home/zhanelya/package.json  
npm ERR! code ENOENT  
npm ERR! errno -2  
npm ERR! syscall open  
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/zhanelya/package.json'  
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.  
npm ERR! enoent  

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:  
npm ERR!     /home/zhanelya/.npm/_logs/2017-07-05T07_35_34_543Z-debug.log
```

Comment: package.json не может открыть. Он у Вас точно есть там где вы выполняете npm?

Comment: Запускаешь не с папки проекта, вот и ошибка

Answer (score 7, accepted):

При запуске npm ищет файл с именем `package.json`. В этом файле описан проект, его зависимости и прочая конфигурация. Ищется этот файл только в текущей директории, в которой выполнена команда.

Судя по логу, вы выполняете команду `npm start` в директории `/home/zhanelya`, то есть в домашней директории вашего пользователя. Почти наверняка ваш проект находится не там. Найдите директорию проекта и перейдите в неё (`cd path/to/dir`), либо откройте консоль сразу в ней.